# React Native list not being populated with values

Tags: javascript, user-interface, react-native

I'm currently building a list in react native but unfortunately it's not being populated with any values. There are 4 list elements which is consistent with the number in the array. But the items are just empty in the interface.

```js
    render() {
console.log(this.state.friends);
/*logs [
Array [
  Object {
"avatar_url": Alice url,
"id": 1,
"name": "alice",
"selected": false,
  },
  Object {
"avatar_url": Bob url,
"id": 2,
"name": "Bob",
"selected": false,
  },
  Object {
"avatar_url": Charlie url,
"id": 3,
"name": "Charlie",
"selected": false,
  },
  Object {
"avatar_url": Dave url,
"id": 4,
"name": "Dave",
"selected": false,
  },
]]*/
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <Content>
      <ScrollView>
        <List containerStyle={{marginBottom: 20}}>
          {
            this.state.friends.map((l, i) => {
              return(<ListItem
            roundAvatar
            avatar={{uri: l.avatar_url}}
            key={i}
            onPress={() => {this.clickedFriend(l)}}
            title={l.name}
            rightIcon={<Icon style={{alignSelf: 'center'}} size={25} name={l.selected ? "check-circle-o" : "times-circle-o"}/>}
          />)
        })
          }
          {/* <ListItem
            onPress={() => {this.inviteFriends()}}
            title="Invite Friends"

          /> */}
        </List>
      </ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.container2}>
              <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <Icon.Button name="arrow-right" backgroundColor="#3b5998" onPress={()=>this.send()}>
                  <Text style={{color: "white"}}>Send</Text>
                </Icon.Button>
              </View>
        </View>
    </Content>
    </View>
  );

  }
```

Comment: Can you share the code for ListItem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is because the map function is not returning anything. The mapping does map through 4 items, hence for listView items, but returns nothing. Inthe map function, try putting your  inside a return(/*ListItem here*/), like this.

```
{
            this.state.friends.map((l, i) => (
              return(<ListItem
                roundAvatar
                avatar={{uri: l.avatar_url}}
                key={i}
                onPress={() => {this.clickedFriend(l)}}
                title={l.name}
                rightIcon={<Icon style={{alignSelf: 'center'}} size={25} name={l.selected ? "check-circle-o" : "times-circle-o"}/>}
              />)
            ))
          }
```

Comment: Still not actually, let me update the code in the question.

Comment: Oops! Try this instead, just add /*return*/  just before map starting line. So it will be `return this.state.friends.map((l, i) => (.....`

Comment: Do let me know if it works, so I can edit my answer.

Comment: Still nothing actually :/

Comment: Sure I'm using the ListItem from native-base, here: http://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#list-def-headref

Comment: Found the issue now actually. Thanks for the help! It was because I was using List and ListItem from native-base when I should have been using from React-Native-Elements.